# How to get the http response for NSURLConnection without using delegates

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I would like to know if there is a way to get the HTTP response for a `NSURLConnection` without making use of the delegate provided by Apple.

For example if I setup a connection in the following manner:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"player.UpdateProfile" forHTTPHeaderField:@"player-profile"];
[self addHttpHeaders:request];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately: YES];
```

Now here instead of delegating to `self` and parsing the response in the `didReceiveResponse` method, can I create a custom delegate where I can parse the response? I don't need a complete tutorial on how to do it but a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can set the delegate to any object you wish, as long as that object conforms to the protocol defined by the delegate.

Comment: Look into AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) on GitHUB.  It is a pretty incredible library that encapsulates this functionality and makes it really easy to use.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom delegate"? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection is probably easier to use these days with:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: urlRequest
                                   queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
}
```

This avoids having to create any delegate object at all. Be warned: Its very difficult to cancel this sort of request, so make sure you put safeguards in the response handler.